# JavaScript Validation not working on while loop

Tags: javascript

I was adding validation to my Javascript program and came across an error where this piece of code would only work if the while loop is an if statement, it doesn't take any of the entries into account, e.g. if I enter "yes" nothing happens it just keeps prompting me with the question. Any help would be appreciated!

```
     //This prints the message "the timer has started"
     var messageArea = document.getElementById("messageArea");

     //Time in milliseconds
     var delay = 1000;

     //Displays the timer
     var counterArea = document.getElementById("counterArea");
     //How long the timer is going for
     var counter = 1;
     counterArea.innerHTML = counter;

     var timer = window.setInterval(timerAction, delay);

     function timerAction()
     {
        counter--;
        counterArea.innerHTML = counter;

        while(counter==0)
        {
            //If timer runs out try again
            user_input = prompt("Timer has ran out, would you like to try again?", "Yes or No");
            if (user_input === "yes" && "Yes") 
            {
            //Refreshes the page
            location.reload();
            }
            else if (user_input === "no" && "No") 
            {
            //Once game is complete closes tab
            window.close();
            }
            else {
            alert("Please enter a valid choice, Yes or No");//fix this
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: `user_input === "yes" && "Yes"` doesn’t do what you think it does.

Comment: VERY poor coding practice to have a blocking alert in a setIterval - also your boolean logic is way off. Try `if (user_input.toLowerCase() === "yes")`

Comment: Also use if instead of while - or if you want to loop untile a valid answer, loop on something else than the counter: `while (!okanswer) { ...`

Comment: Start by changing `&&` to `||` in your if statements. You want to check if the input is "Yes" OR "yes", not "Yes" AND "yes".

Comment: @JamesWhiteley that is not enough. JS does not handle `if (something === "x" || "X")`

Comment: D'oh. Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter `yes`, the JavaScript *asynchronously* attempts to trigger a page reload.

This means that when the event loop isn't busy doing something else, the browser will be told to reload the page.

However, the event loop is permanently busy because `counter==0` so the `while` loop will never end.

You need to exit the `while` loop before the reload will happen.

Comment: Also `if (user_input === "no" && "No")` is off

Answer (score -2):

Fixed it by adding a break after the if statements.

```
      while (counter == 0) {
          //If timer runs out try again
          user_input = prompt("Timer has ran out, would you like to try again?", "Yes or No");
          if (user_input === "yes" && "Yes") {
              //Refreshes the page
              location.reload();
              break;
          } else if (user_input === "no" && "No") {
              //Once game is complete closes tab
              window.close();
              break;
          } else {
              //Validation for input
              alert("Please enter a valid choice, Yes or No");
          }
      }
```

Comment: Your code is not doing what you think it does. `user_input === "yes" && "Yes"` is NOT testing if the user input is "yes" or the user input is "YES" - that is not how javascript boolean logic works